# Call the native Android/iOS Sharing function from webpage

Tags: android, mobile, share

I am currently working on the sharing system for a mobile website.

I would like to implement a link on the html like :

```
< a href= "share:http://www.urltoshare.com" > Share < / a >
```

This link should open the Share dialog on the Android device. 
Same on iphone.

I am wondering if it is possible.

It is possible for other action like :

```
< a href = " mailto:email@email.com " > email < / a >
```

or

```
< a href = " sms:05262737383 " > Sms < / a >
```

Thanks